# Получить время из MediaPlayerElement

Tags: c#, uwp

Есть элемент MediaPlayerElement, полученный в xaml. Мне нужно получить из него номер кадра, фреймтайм и время в формате {Минуты}:{Секунды}:{Миллисекунды}. Так же по идее нужна возможность управлять плеером, то есть ставить на паузу/продолжить, перемотать видео.

Comment: Что нужно - понятно, а где вопрос? Покажите ваш код, расскажите, что именно не получается. Получается ли читать [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement?view=winrt-19041)?

Comment: @aepot Дело то в том, что этого нет в документации! Ни слова про контроль медиа элемента. Если он не контролируем, то я просто найду или напишу другой, но если возможно лучше использовать этот. А без документации и кода нет.

Comment: Странно, что [в документации нет даже намёка на возможность управлять содержимым](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.mediaplayer). Поищите, может там есть [специальные классы созданные как раз для для управления воспроизведением](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.playbacksession)? Наверняка, можно даже найти [официальные гайды по работе с медиа](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback)...